# Count subdocuments that match a given criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My Mongo collection has document of the form:

```
{
    ...
    "notifications": [
        {
            "enabled": true,
            "groups": [ "NG1", "NG3" ]
        },
        {
            "enabled": false,
            "groups": []
        }
    ]
}
```

where `enabled` is boolean and `groups` is a list of strings.
I need to perform a query to identify how many entries in `notifications` have `enabled = true` and contain a given string in `groups` (e.g. `NG3`).

Previously, without the `enabled` property which was introduced later as requirement, my query was simply

```
db.collection.find({ "notifications.groups": "NG3" })
```

I tried a few combinations with `$and` operator but with no luck, so any suggestion is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Would recommend running an aggregation framework pipeline that uses a combination of the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)** and **[`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size)** array operators within a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline step.

The **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)** operator will return an array with elements in a subset of the array that match a specified condition. The **[`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size)** will simply return the number of elements in that filtered array.

So, putting this altogether, you have this pipeline to run so that you can identify how many entries in notifications have `enabled = true` and contain a given string in groups (e.g. "NG3"):

```
var pipeline = [
    { "$match": { "notifications.enabled": true, "notifications.groups": "NG3" } },
    {
        "$project": {
            "numberOfEntries": {
                "$size": {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": "$notifications",
                        "as": "items",
                        "cond": { 
                            "$and": [
                                { "$eq": [ "$$items.enabled", true ] },
                                { "$setIsSubset": [ [ "NG3" ], "$$items.groups" ] }
                            ] 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
];

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

---

The above works for MongoDB versions `3.2.X` and newer. However, for a solution that covers MongoDB versions `2.6.X up to and including 3.0.X`, other array operators like **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)**, **[`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)** would be good substitute operators for
filtering arrays.

Consider using the **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** operator to filter the array using the same logic as above in the $cond as your mapping expression. The **[`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)** operator then returns a set with elements that appear in the first set but not in the second set; i.e. performs a relative compliment of the second set relative to the first. In this case it will return the final notifications array that has elements not related to the parent documents via the `enabled` and `groups` properties.

```
var pipeline = [   
    { "$match": { "notifications.enabled": true, "notifications.groups": "NG3" } },
    {
        "$project": {
            "numberOfEntries": {
                "$size": {
                    "$setDifference": [
                        {
                            "$map": {
                                "input": "$notifications",
                                "as": "items",
                                "in": {
                                    "$cond": [
                                        { "$and": [
                                            { "$eq": [ "$$items.enabled", true ] },
                                            { "$setIsSubset": [ [ "NG3" ], "$$items.groups" ] }
                                        ] },
                                        "$$items",
                                        false
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        [false]
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
];

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

---

For older MongoDB versions which do not have the above operators, consider using the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)**, **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** and **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** operators to achieve the same objective:

```
var pipeline = [
    { "$match": { "notifications.enabled": true, "notifications.groups": "NG3" } },
    { "$unwind": "$notifications" },
    { "$match": { "notifications.enabled": true, "notifications.groups": "NG3" } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "numberOfEntries": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
];
db.collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Comment: This is way more than I expected as a suggestion!! I learned a bunch from your answers, so thank you very much chridam and Ali Dehghani!!

Comment: @ilPittiz No worries, always happy to help :)

Answer (score 4):

## Count the documents

---

Use `$elemMatch`:

```
db.collection.find({
    "notifications": {
         "$elemMatch": {
               "enabled": true,
               "groups": "NG3"
         }
     }
})
```

The [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria.

The problem with the following query:

```
db.collection.find({ "notifications.groups": "NG3", "notifications.enabled": true })
```

Is that the field references aren't restricted to a single notification. So, this query will match as long as one of the notifications is `enabled` 
as `true` and one contains an `NG3` in its `groups`, but what you want is for both attributes to apply to the same notification. In order to restrict the matching process, you should use the `$elemMatch` operator.

## Count notifications individually

---

If you want to count the number of notifications with that criteria, you should use an *Aggregation Pipeline*, as @chridam explained in depth in his answer. 
 I recommend the following four stages to count the notifications:

1. Throw everything away and just keep the notifications
2. Expand the `notifications` array, generating one notification
   document for each array element
3. Keep those notifications with `{enabled: true, groups: "NG3"}`
4. Count the remaining notifications

Then define these four variables corresponding to each stage:

```
var keepNotification = {$project: {
                                      "notifications.enabled": 1, 
                                      "notifications.groups": 1, 
                                      _id: 0
                                  }
                       }

var expandNotifications = {$unwind: "$notifications"}

var filterByEnabledAndGroups = {$match: {
                                            "notifications.enabled": true,  
                                            "notifications.groups": "NG3"
                                        }
                               }

var count = {$group: {_id: "notifications", count: {$sum: 1}}}
```

And use them in your aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
                            keepNotification, 
                            expandNotifications, 
                            filterByEnabledAndGroups, 
                            count
                       ])
```

The final result would be something like:

```
{ "_id" : "notifications", "count" : 5 }
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right but his previous approach `db.collection.find({ "notifications.groups": "NG3" })` made me believe that he wants to count all the documents.

Comment: You're right, sorry for the confusion! My approach was to focus on the query first, so i was performing a simple query on the whole collection.
Your answer and chridam's one show the 2 sides of the same problem, so thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Actually the optimal way to do this is in MongoDB 3.2 or newer because you can  or use the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37480812/3100115) or take advantage of the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) accumulator operator available in the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage which can be used to return a sum of all elements in an array.

Let see how we can do this using `$sum` in the `$project` stage.

In the `$project` stage, you need to use the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator to return an array where items in the array are "numeric" `1` or `0`. To do that, we need a logical condition using the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator which returns `1` when the condition is `true` and `0` when it's `false`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "notifications.enabled": true, 
        "notifications.groups": "NG3" 
    }},
    { "$project": { 
        "count": { 
            "$sum": { 
                "$map": { 
                    "input": "$notifications", 
                    "as": "n", 
                    "in": { 
                        "$cond": [ 
                            { "$and": [ 
                                "$$n.enabled", 
                                    { "$setIsSubset": [ 
                                        [ "NG3" ], 
                                        "$$n.groups"
                                    ]}
                            ]}, 
                            1, 
                            0
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Prior MongoDB 3.2, you need to take a different approach which is less efficient because it requires that we [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) our array after the `$project` stage because the `$sum` operator is not available in the `$project` stage from 3.0 backwards.

From there, you simply [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) your documents and use the `$sum` operator to return the count.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "notifications.enabled": true, 
        "notifications.groups": "NG3" 
    }},
    { "$project": { 
        "count": { 
            "$map": { 
                "input": "$notifications", 
                "as": "n", 
                "in": { 
                    "$cond": [ 
                        { "$and": [ 
                            "$$n.enabled", 
                                { "$setIsSubset": [ 
                                    [ "NG3" ], 
                                    "$$n.groups"
                                ]}
                        ]}, 
                        1, 
                        0
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$count" }, 
    { "$group": { "_id": "$_id", "count": { "$sum": "$count" } } }
])
```

The two queries produces something like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57487d006a2fa1f11efc3208"), "count" : 1 }
```

Comment: Thank you for another great detailed answer! I'll never stop learning how powerful is Mongo 3.2 :)